# WebStorm place imports on individual lines when more than 3

Tags: webstorm

I'm looking for a way to have the imports placed on individual lines when organizing imports with more than 3 items per module and if less kept on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such settings, but you can set **ES6 import/export** option in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces** to **Wrap if long** and set the **Hard wrap at:** (max line length) accordingly